# how to prevent a material-ui package from overriding my app style?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, emotion

I am using the latest Material-UI installation in a React-Gatsby app.
I installed a third party package for a carousel ([react-material-ui-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-material-ui-carousel)).

When I use this package I see it overrides some of my material-ui styles by adding css divs that compete with my app's css divs.

[image]

the `data-emotion` divs are added by my app, and the `data-jss` style divs are added by the package `react-material-ui-carousel`.

Is there a way to limit the carousel styling only to the carousel component and not impact the other material-ui components on my page?
(for example the `MuiButtonBase` contains the `MuiButtonBase-root` rules that override my site's rules)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `StylesProvider` from `@material-ui/core/styles` with this you can put prefix to classes names and avoid styles override

```js
import {
  MuiThemeProvider,
  ThemeProvider,
  StylesProvider,
  createGenerateClassName,
} from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName({
  seed: 'classes-custom-prefix',
});

export const Provider = ({ children, theme }) => {
  return (
    <StylesProvider generateClassName={generateClassName}>
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    </StylesProvider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try to check your package-lock
and use 3 blocs

```
"node_modules/react-material-ui-carousel": {
  "version": "2.3.7-mui5",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-material-ui-carousel/-/react-material-ui-carousel-2.3.7-mui5.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-XM6+kn6db++riBKUufl7XQI8eE/qj5XWpkDpHUWnioICCdUqx6cvWJmIqjBqcMNB4FgcgJFVmsE3iEKs/4gRIA==",
  "dependencies": {
    "auto-bind": "^2.1.1",
    "react-swipeable": "^6.1.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.0.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.0.0",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  }
},

"react-material-ui-carousel": {
  "version": "2.3.7-mui5",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-material-ui-carousel/-/react-material-ui-carousel-2.3.7-mui5.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-XM6+kn6db++riBKUufl7XQI8eE/qj5XWpkDpHUWnioICCdUqx6cvWJmIqjBqcMNB4FgcgJFVmsE3iEKs/4gRIA==",
  "requires": {
    "auto-bind": "^2.1.1",
    "react-swipeable": "^6.1.0"
  }
},
    "react-material-ui-carousel": "^2.3.7-mui5",
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues/inconsistencies with styles between production and deploy. For me, the best way to style elements and override MUI styles without "!important" is using:

```
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const CustomButton = styled(Button)(({ theme }) => ({
  display: "flex",
  ...
}));
```

And then instead of using

`<Button ...args>label</Button>`

use

`<CustomButton ...args>label</CustomButton>`